# How can I convert HTML entities?

Tags: html, perl

I am reading in a large string in Perl from a webpage using WWW::Mechanzie. Am not writing it into a file, just going through it. However apostrophes are coming out as &#27. Is there a way to automatically convert the entire string so that I get ' instead of its character code?

Comment: You can use [HTML::Entities](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Entities)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To decode strings with HTML entities you can use the `decode()` method in [`HTML::Entities`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Entities). For example:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use HTML::Entities;
my $str = "An &#39example&#39";
say decode_entities($str);
```

**Output**:

```
An 'example'
```